# Insert Span into TextBlock programmatically

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to create the following snippet programmatically:

```
<TextBlock>
    12.01.2013
    <Span xml:space="preserve" Foreground="#FFCCCCCC"> 21:09</Span>
</TextBlock>
```

But `TextBlock` seems not to support `TextPointer`s, so I cannot see a way to insert a `Span`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me for Phone 7.1:

C#

```
var tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Inlines.Add("12.01.2013");

var span = new Span { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) };
span.Inlines.Add(" 21:09");
tb.Inlines.Add(span);

content.Content = tb;
```

Xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="content"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I wonder why this is not mentioned in the msdn `Span` documentation.